# Bootstrap h1 top-margin on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.2 with this code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background:red;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            first container
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="background:yellow;">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background:blue;">
            <h1>seconds container with h1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But on smaller screens <1280px, I get the yellow part, which makes a margin to the h1 tag, I don't want.

The result can be seen here:

[image]

What can I do to remove the yellow part (margin before h1 on smaller screens)?

Comment: You know you don't have to make rows for col-12's right or define column width at all?  You don't need to define it at all.  It is already implied.

Comment: Can you please provide the jsfiddle of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on small resolutions `col-md-12` class is not triggered (it's for "medium" resolutions) so `float: left` and `width: 100%` styles are not applied causing the gap you are observing.

To solve the issue you can use `col-xs-12` classes instead:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background:red;">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            first container
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background:yellow;">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background:blue;">
            <h1>seconds container with h1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/jTwSD7Kx1T4hXwdJy0wF?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.you can use media queries

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
       @media(max-width:767px){
       .removeh1margin h1{margin:0;}
    }
    @media(min-width:768px){
   .removeh1margin h1{margin:0;}
}
    @media(min-width:992px){
   .removeh1margin h1{margin:0;}
}
    @media(min-width:1200px){
  .removeh1margin h1{margin:0;}
}

    </style>
   
  </head>

  <body>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="background:red;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                first container
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row removeh1margin"  style="background:yellow;">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="background:blue;">
                <h1>seconds container with h1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```